# cabal failures, how to move to cabal-dev?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I seem to have so many problems with broken dependency graphs in cabal, that I am finally trying to follow SO advice to move to cabal-dev, but for similar reasons it won't install.

Skipping the many pages of the original install attempts, here is the current status:

```
C:\Users\me>cabal --force-reinstalls install cabal-dev
Resolving dependencies...
Warning: Note that reinstalls are always dangerous. Continuing anyway...
Configuring network-2.3.1.0...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler, --with-gcc
configure: error: cannot find sources (include/HsNet.h) in /e/plang/Libraries/wx
Widgets2.9 or ..
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
HTTP-4000.2.5 depends on network-2.3.1.0 which failed to install.
cabal-dev-0.9.1 depends on network-2.3.1.0 which failed to install.
network-2.3.1.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I did just re-install network (current version seems to be 2.4.0.1), but that did not help.

It is also interesting that although one finds various strong declarations NOT to use cabal, many /most/ tutorials and books recommend it (by default?).

Comment: I don't think anyone says not to use `cabal`, they just complain about it. `cabal-dev` won't help you here, the problem was that so many versions of `network` were installed in `System`. I think you should uninstall all versions of everything and make sure in the future that nothing is installed in `System` that did not come with the Haskell Platform. `cabal install` should only affect the local collection of packages; then the worst case is unregistering them and reinstalling, with the HP intact. `cabal dev` itself just starts a new registry of packages, and makes it convenient to use.

Comment: I have only done very pedestrian "cabal install" package installations, yet have many package version and shadowing problems. I was referred to: "repeat after me, cabal is not a package manager", and also saw in the haskwllwiki/cabal "Cabal is only involved in the creation of packages and the building of their contents. It does not manage packages. Cabal-Install installs cabal packages. ... Furthermore, Cabal-Install is not a fully featured package manager. " The advice to avoid these problems was to convert to cabal-dev. Now with the force's to install this I have 61 broken packages. Argh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to ever install different versions of packages coming with Platform.

In this case you are trying to reinstall `network`. You should do the following: run `ghc-pkg list network`. If you have more than one version installed use `ghc-pkg unregister` to unregister all but the oldest version.

Then perform `cabal install cabal-dev network-2.3.0.13` or whatever version was shipped with latest platform.

Comment: Ok. the list shows that I have 4 Networks installed, three in System one in user directory. Not sure how they all got installed. I also have 3 versions of Haskell-platform, should I unregister the older ones? I had assumed that a simple cabal install would install the most recent and thus current Network (or anything), why manually roll back to an older one?

Comment: Well, it seems to have worked, thanks! Now to see what else got broken through all the --force'ing!